# Python: how to interpret y from solve_ivp

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, differential-equations

This is surely a trivial question, but it prevents my complete understanding of `solve_ivp` from `scypy.integrate` on which I am presently training ...
The image below defines the problem I'm trying to solve with `solve_ivp`:

[image]

So, in order to find `y(t)`, I specify the function to integrate, the initial values, the time span, and then I run `solve_ivp`, as shown in the code below:

```
# Function to integrate
def fun(t, u):    
    x1 = u[0]     # "u": function to found / 4 components x1, x2, x3 and x4
    x2 = u[1]
    x3 = u[2]
    x4 = u[3]

    dx1_dt = 1   # "u'(t) = F(t,u(t))": derivatives of components
    dx2_dt = x3
    dx3_dt = x4
    dx4_dt = np.exp(x1) + 5*x2 - x1*x3
    
    return [dx1_dt, dx2_dt, dx3_dt, dx4_dt]

# Specify initial conditions
x1_0 = 0.0
x2_0 = 0.0
x3_0 = 0.0
x4_0 = 0.0

y_0 = np.array([x1_0, x2_0, x3_0, x4_0])

# Specify initial and final times
t0 = 0.0  
tf = 10.0 

t_span = np.array([t0, tf])

# Resolution
position = solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y_0, method='RK45', max_step=0.1)
```

Now, `solve_ivp` returns a `ndarray` named `y` (in the present case, it will be `position.y`, of shape `(4, 104)`) which according to the `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` documentation, gives the *"Values of the solution at t"*.

So far, it's good.

**My Question is just**:

In the present problem, what are the values giving `y(t)` : `y[0], y[1], y[2]` or `y[3]`? As far as I understood how `solve_ivp` works, it should be `y[1]`, corresponding to the second line of vector `u(t)`. Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, `position.y[1]` contains the values for the solution function `y(t)`. You should also find that `position.y[0]` coincides with `position.t`.

If you want additional values or a faster computation, use the `teval` or `dense_output` options. With the `max_step` argument you are forcing more than 100 internal steps. Without that and one of the other options, the number of internal steps is adapted to the internal error tolerance and usually less. You get the values at the desired points then from the piecewise polynomial interpolation function, either implicitly with `teval=...` or explicitly with the inclusion of the "dense output" interpolation function in the return object as `position.sol`.

Comment: Thank you @Lutz for all those informations. it should help me a lot in better understanding this method with so many possible parameters.